# Is there a way in Python to multiprocess on data which is some times incomplete due to improper network or any other issues?

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-multiprocessing, quantitative-finance

I have been trying to look for a solution in multiprocessing in python where the data gets corrupted some times due to a bad network of interruption in the network. Is there a way I can possibly implement in a WHILE loop so that I can move on with other iterations rather than being stuck with the current iteration's error. I am also not able to catch the exception for now. Any help will be appreciated.

Failed to catch exceptions inside while loop

```py
def get_quotes(quote):
    quotes = kite.quote(instrument_token)
    quote.put_nowait(quotes)


def start():
    while True:
        try:
            quotes_recieved = Queue()
            quotes_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_quotes, args=(quotes_recieved,))
            quotes_process.start()
            quotes = quotes_recieved.get()
            print(quotes)
        except:
            sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        start()
    except Exception:
        sys.exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

I expect that the multiprocess runs smoothly even when there is a network exception and how I can handle network exception

Comment: You can handle the exception in the target function: `get_quotes`.

Comment: That worked..Thanks!..Error in multiprocessing got handled

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the exception in the target function: `get_quotes`